# How to divide internet after installing PFsense in VM

Tags: router, pfsense

I have installed PFsense inside VM and used two ethernet cards as descrivbed in their manual.

My WAN IP = 10.0.11.113
My LAN IP = 192.1768.2.1

Now after installing I am getting only DOS type interface.

Now how can I divide internet to other VMs through PFsense

Answer (score 2):

To configure PFSense, you need to browse to its web address (which will be in your case be http://192.168.2.1). It will then take you through the configuration wizard.

Comment: The internet is now working through PFsense but in Virtual machines only. I am confused now how my existing users can connect through pfsense. Currently config is

1) modem---router---my server (dhcp,dns,ad)----VM(pfsense)---VM2(gets internet from eth2 via pfsense)....\

ALl others users get ip from my server , i don't know how to pass them through pfsense

Comment: What you need to do is point your Default Gateway for the client machines to point to the LAN IP address of the PFSense box.

Comment: but when i ping that address from clients its not working , its on different subnet.....
That ip only works if i join the VM machines with that adapter as their main adapter

Comment: You will need to make sure that the LAN address is on the same subnet as the rest of your network, and your WAN address needs to be on a *different* subnet. This also ensures that users can't just bypass the pfsense by entering the IP of the router into their gateway.

Comment: PFsense is getting WANIP from router which is same subnet as other computer on network like 10.0.11.2 ,4,4 . My WANIP is 10.0.11.113.
The internal LANIP is 192.168.1.1(LAN gateway).  Now the VM which is joined with PFsense Adapter got ip 192.168.1.2. Now when i ping 10.0.11.2(any other lan) It says unreachable and if i ping 192.168.1.1 from the computer with ip 10.0.11.3 then it says unreachable. How can i make them same subnet